# apache kafka partition,java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Im very new to apache kafka, and i am trying to do kafka partitions while sending my string to kafka,

[doing exactly same as here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3066873/big-data/big-data-messaging-with-kafka-part-2.html)

```
 public class Producer {
    public static void main(String[] argv)throws Exception {

           String topicName = "test";

           //Configure the Producer
           Properties configProperties = new Properties();
           configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"192.168.4.226:9092");
           configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
           configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
           configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG,CountryPartitioner.class.getCanonicalName());
           configProperties.put("partitions.0","USA");
           configProperties.put("partitions.1","India"); 

           org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer producer = new KafkaProducer(configProperties);
               ProducerRecord<String, String> rec = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName,"message111");
               producer.send(rec, new Callback() {
                   public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
                       System.out.println("Message sent to topic ->" + metadata.topic() +" stored at offset->" + metadata.offset());
                   }
               });
           producer.close();
       }


}
```

Now i'm getting an exception like this

```
2018-07-03 17:52:12 ERROR RecordBatch:102 - Error executing user-provided callback on message for topic-partition test-2:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.spnotes.kafka.partition.Producer$1.onCompletion(Producer.java:29)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordBatch.done(RecordBatch.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordBatch.maybeExpire(RecordBatch.java:136)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.abortExpiredBatches(RecordAccumulator.java:220)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:141)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

what i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kafka is already running and if i try without partition, it will work smooth.

Comment: If you look at the stack trace, you'll see that your logic hit a `NullPointerException` on the sysout line, so it looks like `metadata` is null. The javadoc [1] says `metadata` can be null if there was an exception. So check for `null` properly and print the exception if there's one like for example in [2]

[1]: http://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback.html#onCompletion-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata-java.lang.Exception-
[2]: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples/Producer.java#L82-L101

Comment: did you create topic with partitions? what is the purpose of "partitions.0" configuration?

Comment: @MickaelMaison as per your examples, i'm getting org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch Expired

Comment: any specific way to create partitions with above scenario @gagansingh??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 3: Only thing is you have to create multiple partitions, see these steps.First we make a config file for each of the brokers (on Windows use the copy command instead)

```
> cp config/server.properties config/server-1.properties
> cp config/server.properties config/server-2.properties
```

Now edit these new files and set the following properties:

```
config/server-1.properties:
    broker.id=1
    listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093
    log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs-1

config/server-2.properties:
    broker.id=2
    listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9094
    log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs-2
```

We already have Zookeeper and our single node started, so we just need to start the two new nodes:

```
> bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-1.properties &
> bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-2.properties &
```

**Now create a new topic with a replication factor of three along with 3 partitions** 
 it would solve the issue:

```
> bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3 --topic my-replicated-topic
```

Comment: Multiple partitions will still work on a single broker

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the clarification, i have edited the answer,